# Zend_Paginator / Doctrine 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-paginator

I'm using Doctrine 2 with my Zend Framework application and a typical query result could yield a million (or more) search results.

I want to use Zend_Paginator in line with this result set. However, I don't want to return all the results as an array and use the Array adapter as this would be inefficient, instead I would like to supply the paginator the total amount of rows then and array of results based on limit/offset amounts.

Is this doable using the Array adapter or would I need to create my own pagination adapter?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to extend your own adapter. The Array adapter works the way you don't want  - it receives an array and return a portion of it based on the current settings. What you'll need is a new adapter that will take DQL statemenet and set the limit/offset.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface**, as it is already implement by **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator**.

Instead can simply pass Doctrine's **Paginator** to **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator** like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination as Paginator; // goes at top of file

SomeController::someAction() 
{
 $dql = "SELECT s, c FROM Square\Entity\StampItem s JOIN s.country c ".' ORDER BY '.  $orderBy . ' ' . $dir;
 
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
 $d2_paginator = new Paginator($query); 
 
 $d2_paginator_iter = $d2_paginator->getIterator(); // returns \ArrayIterator object
 
 $adapter =  new \Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator($d2_paginator_iter);
  
 $zend_paginator = new \Zend_Paginator($adapter);          
                       
 $zend_paginator->setItemCountPerPage($perPage)
            ->setCurrentPageNumber($current_page);

 $this->view->paginator = $zend_paginator; 
}
```

Then you use paginator in the view script just like you ordinarly do.

### Explanation:

**Zend_Paginator**'s constructor can take a **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface**, which **Zend_Paginator_Adpater_Iterator** implements.  Now, **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator**'s constructor takes an **\Iterator** interface. This **\Iterator** must also implement **\Countable** (as you can see by looking at **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator**'s constructor). Since **Paginator::getIterator()** method returns an **\ArrayIterator**, it by definition it fits the bill (since **\ArrayIterator** implements both **\Iterator** and **\Countable**).

See this port from Doctrine 1 to Docrine 2 of the code for "Zend Framework: A Beginner's Guide" from Doctrine 1 to Doctrine:  https://github.com/kkruecke/zf-beginners-doctrine2. It includes code for paginating with **Zend_Paginator** using **Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator** with Doctrine 2' **Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator**.